Auto Expand and Checkbox Detail Row
So is there a way to have a check box list and if the check box is checked a detail row is automatically expanded to enter answers for a supporting question.
What I have is the closest I can get but requires additional "clicking" on the user's part that I want to minimize (i.e they would have to click the expand '+' sign to answer the supporting questions) They would also have to click the drop down to see the initial choices and add a row if they want to select more initial choices
Dynamic Matrix - Single column with expanded detail row

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Can you please clarify more to help us understand your requirement?
For example - can you solve this with a single boolean question for the checkbox and conditional visibility of the supporting question. This will give you more freedom over the types of question/supporting question combinations. Here is a small Plunker to show this - https://plnkr.co/edit/79xvzluaJFoS0o0A
If this is not working for you as an approach, can you share why you need dynamic matrix over other options?
